# Regex for numbers between 1-31 and optional commas between numbers

Tags: regex

I'm not very good with regex, maybe this is an easy one for you regex experts out there!

Basically I need the option for a user to enter a number between 1 and 31 (without any trailing zeroes) with optional commas (1 comma only) between them e.g.

Valid:

- 1
- 1,22,31

Invalid:

- A
- 31,33,333
- 2,,
- 1,2.,3%
- 0,1,2,3

So far I've tried:

```
^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]),?\d+$
```

but it's already starting to go wrong I think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want:

```
^(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])(?:,(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]))*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/PASyUn/1)

Comment: Same here :) +1 `[0-1]` can be `[01]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird: True, but I keep it just for making a difference beween our answers ;-)

Comment: I will remove mine, you were first.

Comment: Great! Seems to work, the other answer also works so I'll use either - thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost fine with your regex except that final `\d+` and you should enclose it entirely within a cluster and choose a quantifier for it. Try this instead:

```
^(?:(?:[12]\d|3[01]|[1-9]),?\b)+$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/G0nYGE/5)

Comment: Great! Seems to work, the other answer also works so I'll use either - thank you!!